# Django ImageField upload_to path

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble understanding and using Django's ImageField.

I have a model:

```
class BlogContent(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/static_dirs/images/')
    description = models.TextField()
```

My file system is currently:

```
src
 |---main_project
 |---app_that_contains_blog_content_model
 |---static
       |---static_dirs
                |---images
```

When I run the server and go to the Admin page, I can add BlogContent objects. After choosing an image for the image field, the image has a temporary name. However, after I save this object I can't find the image in the folder specified by the upload_to path.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your image would be uploaded to the `media` folder, so it's better to change the path in the model like `images/`, and they will be uploaded to `media/images`

In `settings.py` add this

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

In `url.py`

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [
   ....
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And then, if you want to display all these images, use something like this
in `view.py`
`BlogContent.objects.all()`

And render it like this:

```
{% for img in your_object %}
    <img src="{{ img.image.url }}" >
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: for use in development mode add this code in main urls.py from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Answer (score 17):

`static` in `upload_to` doesnot make sense, since user-uploaded images go into `media/` folder.. you need these:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog/%Y/%m/%d')
```

and all images land in:

```
media/blog/2016/01/02/img_name.jpg
```

you access it in template like this:

```
<img src="{{ blog.image.url }}">
```

in settings:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use media path, instead static. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

Comment: Thanks! Figured it out. The images are in the media folder.