# Get image url from django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have dificulties to get the image url out of django form.

Model:

```
class Sponsor(models.Model):
    image = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='sponsors/', 
                                processors=[SmartResize(300, 120, upscale=False)],
                                format='JPEG', 
                                options={'quality': 100}, 
                                null=True)
```

Form:

```
class SponsorForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Sponsor
        fields = ('image',)
```

When I render it using:

```
{{ sponsorform.image }}
```

It prints:

```
Currently: <a href="/media/sponsors/random1.jpg">sponsors/random1.jpg</a> <br>Change: <input id="id_sponsor-image" name="sponsor-image" type="file">
```

So my question is, how to get that url in templates? I've tried:

```
{{ sponsorform.image.url }}
{{ sponsorform.image.path }}
{{ sponsorform.image.href }}
```

But nothing seems to work, any suggestions?

Comment: I think it is same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563454/django-imagefield-upload-to-path/34563512#34563512  You can check my answer

Comment: @Baterson: I think OP tried to get the image url from a form not from objects.

Comment: @ShangWang yes, you rigth, I did not notice

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should try `{{ sponsorform.instance.image.url }}`. In case the form is unbounded, you can just do:

```
{% if sponsorform.instance.image %}
    {{ sponsorform.instance.image.url }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: It's working if there is an image but for new form instances it raises: ValueError at /onsite_api/get_sponsor_form/-1/ The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: Of course, I thought you would expect that to happen. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Those attributes are inside `formfield.value`, so:

```
{{ sponsorform.image.value.url }}
{{ sponsorform.image.value.path }}
{{ sponsorform.image.value.href }}
```