# Django - display image from database in edit form

Tags: django, forms, image

I recorded a form that also contained an image. I would like that later in edit form
to be able to visually see the previously uploaded image before changing it. I tried to display it in edit form via

```
<img src = "{{curs.poster_curs.url}}" alt = "alternate text">
```

but in inspect it shows src = "unknown". How can I display the image already uploaded in edit form? I ask for a solution in this regard. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After i search on internet i got the answer here([Get image url from django form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34614012/get-image-url-from-django-form)). The solution is to change the src image from `{{curs.poster_curs.url}}` in `{{form.instace.poster_curs.url}}`. Thank you **[juanifioren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3877259/juanifioren)** .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).