# Storing images in Django model and media folder

Tags: django, image

I have been following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563454/django-imagefield-upload-to-path)

However I do not understand this part in which the answer states

In url.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
urlpatterns = [....
]
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Now

In my project if I add

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

after my

```
 urlpatterns = [....
    ]
```

I get the error

```
    + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'list'
```

any suggestions on how i can fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```